# Why do I store two characters in an array instead of one?

Tags: c

I have this script written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int k = 65;
    char key[1];
    printf("%s\n", key);
    key[0] = k;
    printf("%s\n", key);
}
```

The first printf() gives nothing as expected. But the second one prints 'AA' instead of just A. What is the reason for this? I want it only to print A. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot print a single char as a C string.

Comment: %s expects a null terminated string, key is an array of 1 byte long, and key[1] is whatever is in the stack afterwards, you should really read how C strings work, besides, your first print works on uninitialized memory - and in this case, always expect the unexpected.

Comment: “As expected” then expectation is wrong. The single element in the array is not defined so whatever happens is acceptable since everything here is undefined behavior.

Comment: use %c if you want to print a single character

Comment: Why do you expect the first printf to give nothing?  I expect it to spew a bunch of random garbage, or print nothing, or cause nasal demons to fly out of your nose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change `printf("%s\n", key);`

to:

```
            printf("%c\n", *key);
```

to print only the char

Answer (score 1):

The `%s` format specifier prints a string, which is a NUL terminated sequence of characters in an array.  Your `key` array just has a character, and no NUL terminator, so you get Undefined Behavior.

To legally print a string with `%s` you need to pass (a pointer to) an array containing a NUL-terminated sequence, which you can do by declaring it as `char key[2];` and setting `key[1] = '\0'`.  Alternately, you can use `%c` to print a single character (in which case you need to pass the character, not an array -- eg `printf("%c\n", key[0]);`)

Comment: Thanks for your help Chris. Better sooner than later to learn the significance of null terminators and how memory is managed in C :)